# How can i give the right datetimepattern to my LocalDate.parse?

Tags: java

How can i have my date to show like `26-10-1994`?

if i print this out it will show `1994-10-26` for some wierd reason. anyone have some tips on how to fix this? i've tried local_root but that didnt help either.

```
private String geboortedatum = "26-10-1994";
public LocalDate calculateAge() {
    DateTimeFormatter sdf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
    LocalDate dob = LocalDate.parse(geboortedatum, sdf);
    System.out.println("dob = " + dob);
    return dob;
}
```

Comment: use the formatter to convert the `LocalDate` to a `String`.

Comment: You *did* "give the right datetimepattern to your `LocalDate.parse`". What you failed to do was to give the right datetimepattern to `LocalDate.format`, instead of (implicitly) calling `LocalDate.toString`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic `toString()` of `LocalDate` prints this out as `1994-10-26`, you need to use a formatter to have the pattern you want

```
public LocalDate calculateAge() {
    DateTimeFormatter sdf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
    LocalDate dob = LocalDate.parse(geboortedatum, sdf);
    String dateFormatted = dob.format(sdf);
    System.out.println("dob = " + dateFormatted);
    return dob;
}
```